# Designing the instantiation and destruction of a class using the pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, architecture, pimpl-idiom

*Note: I've rewritten the question to specify my intend clearer, and make it shorter.*

I'm designing a part of a library which has a few requirements:

- None of the implementation details must be visible from public headers.
- The memory must be managed by the library.
- The client accesses the information it needs through a handle reference.

In order to achieve this, I use the pimpl idiom.

What I'm creating is a way to instantiate a tree of entries, and the user can after instantiating the tree add additional behavior to each entity. The tree is later used by other parts of the library to perform some actions. The entries in the tree do not have to be copied or moved in memory, after allocation their memory address remains fixed even if the parent in the tree is changed.

Because other parts need to access the implementation, there needs to be some way to access it, while preferably restricting it to client code.

I had multiple methods that I described in my original question, but now I'm going to present the one I've implemented, and I think may be one of the best ways of achieving this.

---

### Current approach

- Public constructor takes an (owning) pointer to the implementation class. (1)
- Public destructor. (2)
- Friendship with the implementation class. (3)
- Implementation class provides a static method to get access to the implementation class from a reference to the original class. (4)

#### Entry.h

```
// Public header
#pragma once
class EntryImpl;
class Entry final
{
private:
    // 3. Friendship with the implementation class
    friend class EntryImpl;
    EntryImpl* const m_Impl;

public:
    // 1. Constructor takes owning pointer to EntryImpl
    Entry(EntryImpl* impl) : m_Impl(impl) { }
    // 2. Public destructor
    ~Entry() { delete m_Impl; }

    // Public APIs here...
};
```

#### EntryImpl.h

```
// Private header
#pragma once
class EntryImpl final
{
public:
    EntryImpl() { }
    ~EntryImpl() { }

    // 4. Provides the library's internals access to the implementation.
    static EntryImpl& Get(Entry& entry) { return *entry.m_Impl; }

    // As an example function
    void DoSomething() { }
    // Other stuff the implementation does here...
};
```

#### Tree.h

```
// Public header
#pragma once
class Entry;
class TreeImpl;
class Tree final
{
private:
    TreeImpl* const m_Impl;

public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();

    // Public API
    Entry& CreateEntry();

    void DoSomething();
};
```

#### Tree.cpp

```
// Implementation of Tree
#include "Tree.h"
#include "Entry.h"
#include "EntryImpl.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// Implement the forward-declared class
class TreeImpl
{
public:
    TreeImpl() { }
    ~TreeImpl() { }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entry>> m_Entries;
};

Tree::Tree() : m_Impl(new TreeImpl()) { }
Tree::~Tree() { delete m_Impl; }

Entry& Tree::CreateEntry()
{
    // 5. Any constructor parameters can be passed to the private EntryImpl
    //    class and is therefore hidden from the client.
    auto entry = std::make_unique<Entry>(new EntryImpl(/* construction params */));
    Entry& entryRef = *entry;
    // Move it into our own collection
    m_Impl->m_Entries.push_back(std::move(entry));
    return entryRef;
}

void Tree::DoSomething()
{
    for (const auto& entryPtr : m_Impl->m_Entries)
    {
        // 6. Can access the implementation from any implementation
        //    code without modifying the Entry or EntryImpl class.
        EntryImpl& entry = EntryImpl::Get(*entryPtr);
        entry.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

#### Advantages

- Construction parameters of `Entry` are hidden in `EntryImpl`'s constructor. (5)
- Any source file in the library code can access `EntryImpl` without altering `Entry` or `EntryImpl`'s files. (6)
- Works with `std::unique_ptr<Entry>`, without requiring a special deallocator.

#### Disadvantages

- Public destructor allows client code to release the memory of Entry, causing a near immediate crash.
- Friendship? Though most problems associated with friendship aren't prominent here.

---

My question solely regard software design. Are there any alternative approaches that may be better for my scenario? Or just methods I'm overlooking.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your design / restrictions completely. For example: What's the purpose of the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entry>>` (or rather, what's the purpose of `EntryManager`)? Why is `Entry::EntryImpl` const? Is `EntryImpl` copyable, movable, ..?

Comment: Thanks for your response. `EntryImpl` isn't const, the pointer is. Meaning the underlying implementation storage cannot be changed after instantiation. Currently none of the classes are copyable or movable. They'll only be exposed to the consumer of the library as references.

--- I'm mostly working under the restrictions that no implementation details may surface to the consumer of the library. In addition, all memory is managed by the library, and all data given to the client is in form of handles, not actual objects.

Comment: Oops, I meant `Entry::m_Impl`, i.e. the data member. `const` data members are quite troublesome, hence only used for special purposes. -- I'm not entirely sure I understand the relation between *all memory is managed by the library* and *they'll only be exposed as references*. If `EntryImpl` can be copyable, then you can make `Entry` be copyable as well, and not leak any implementation details, for example. Additionally, why can the underlying "implementation storage" not be changed after "instantiation"? What is the relation between an `Entry` object and the `EntryImpl` it refers to?

Comment: I was talking about `Entry::m_Impl` too. I marked the pointer as `const` because I don't intend to change it after the `Entry` is created. I could change the storage of the implementation class (change `Entry::m_Impl`) by marking it non-const, but in my use case that would make no sense. They're not autonomous entities, and it wouldn't make sense to move or copy the memory. Basically, they're an entry point for users to hook in their own customization code, but the users cannot take ownership of these Entry classes.

Comment: I think I begin to understand your design. Still, the purpose of `EntryManagerImpl::m_Entries` is unclear to me. Do you need it just to hold the `Entry`/`EntryImpl` instances somewhere in memory, or does the library need a list of all (current) `EntryImpl` instances? Can there be different objects of type `EntryManager`? If yes, (how) does their behaviour differ? A of the library can request a new `Entry` via `EntryManager::CreateEntry`. Can the user request destruction of a single `Entry` instance? (Does that make sense?)

Comment: Yes, the library both needs to track the memory (to properly clean it up afterwards), and hold a list/other data structure to iterate over it. In the sample I'm just storing it in an `std::vector` but in the real scenario the underlying storage adapts to the stored content (when the data set becomes larger it'll switch over to more efficiently modifiable collections). --- The user can request (deferred) deletion, and it can also change what `EntryManager` it belongs to, but all of that is done by moving the `std::unique_ptr<Entry>` not by reallocating/copying/moving the actual `Entry`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can provide a good answer for your problems. For example, you have not shown any operations for `Entry`s (neither member functions nor free functions taking `Entry&`s). The usage of an `Entry` defines what form (representation) is suitable for it. As far as I can see, you could simply return a (non-owning) pointer from `EntryManager::CreateEntry`, removing most of the purpose of the `Entry` class.

Comment: @dyp I've rewritten the question, hoping to clear up all questions you have/had regarding it. And a happy new year :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a Code Review question now, so you might want to consider posting this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Also, it might not fit well to StackOverflow's philosophy of *specific questions with specific answers, no discussion*. I'll try to present an alternative nevertheless.

---

### Analysis and critique of (details of) the OP's approach

```
Entry(EntryImpl* impl) : m_Impl(impl) { }
// 2. Public destructor
~Entry() { delete m_Impl; }
```

As the OP has already stated, neither of those functions should be called by the user of the library. The destructor invokes Undefined Behaviour if `EntryImpl` has a non-trivial destructor, for example.

In my opinion, there's not much benefit to preventing users from constructing new `Entry` objects. In one of the OP's previous approaches, `Entry`'s constructors were all private. With the OP's current solution, a library user can write:

```
Entry e(0);
```

Which creates an object `e` that cannot be reasonably used. Note that `Entry` should be noncopyable, since it *owns* the object the data member pointer points to.

However, regardless of the definition of class `Entry`, a library user can always create an object that refers to any `Entry` object by using a pointer. (This is an argument against the original implementation that returned an `Entry&` from the tree.)

---

As far as I understand the OP's intentions, an `Entry` object uses a pointer to "extend" its own storage to some fixed memory on the heap:

```
class Entry final
{
private:
    EntryImpl* const m_Impl;
```

Since it is `const`, you can't reseat the pointer. There's also a 1-to-1 relationship between `Entry` objects and `EntryImpl` objects. The library interface however necessarily deals with `EntryImpl` **pointers**. Those are what is essentially passed from the library implementation to the library user. The `Entry` class itself seems to serve only the purpose to establish the 1-to-1 relationship between `Entry` and `EntryImpl` objects.

It is still not entirely clear to me what the relation between `Entry`s and `Tree`s is. It seems as if each `Entry` must belong to a `Tree`, which implies that a `Tree` object should *own* all the entries created from it. This in turn implies that whatever the library user gets from `Tree::AddEntry` should be a *view* on an entry owned by the tree - that is, a pointer. In this light, you should consider the solution below.

---

### An approach using polymorphism

This approach works (only) if you can share a vtable between the library implementation and the library user. Is this is not the case, you can implement a similar approach using an opaque pointer instead of an interface with virtual functions. This even allows defining the library's interface as a C API (see [Hourglass interfaces for C++ APIs](http://youtu.be/PVYdHDm0q6Y)).

Let's take a look at a classic solution to the requirements:

```
// interface headers:

class IEntry // replacement for `Entry`
{
public:
    // public API as virtual functions
};

class Tree
{
    // [implementation]
public:
    IEntry* AddEntry();
    void DoSomething();
};


// implementation headers:

class EntryImpl : public IEntry
{
    // implementation
};

// implementation of `Tree::AddEntry` returns an `EntryImpl*`
```

This solution is useful if an entry handle (`IEntry*`) does not own the entry it refers to. By casting from `IEntry*` to `EntryImpl*`, the library can communicate with more private parts of the entry. There can even be a second interface for the library that separates `EntryImpl` from the `Tree`. No friendship between classes is required for this approach, as far as I can see.

Note that a slightly better solution might be to let the class `EntryImpl` implement a *concept* rather than an interface, and wrap `EntryImpl` objects into an adapter that implements the virtual functions. This allows reusing the `EntryImpl` class for a different interface.

With the above solution, a library user deals with a pointer:

```
Tree myTree;
auto myEntry = myTree.AddEntry();
myEntry->SomeFunction();
```

To document that this pointer does not own the object it points to, you could use what has been named "the world's dumbest smart pointer". Essentially, a lightweight wrapper of a raw pointer that, as a type, expresses that it doesn't own the object it points to:

```
class Tree
{
    // [implementation]
public:
    non_owning_pointer<IEntry> AddEntry();
    void DoSomething();
};
```

---

If you want to allow the user to destruct entries, you should remove them from their tree. Otherwise, you have to deal with destroyed entries explicitly e.g. in `TreeImpl::DoSomething`. At this point, we're starting to rebuild a resource management system for entries; the first step of which typically is destruction. However, the library user might have various requirements on the lifetime of their entries. If you simply return a `shared_ptr`, that might be unnecessary overhead; if you return a `unique_ptr`, the library user might have to wrap that `unique_ptr` in a `shared_ptr`. Even if those solutions don't impact performance very much, I'd consider them strange from a conceptual point of view.

Hence, I'd argue that *for the interface*, you should stick to the most general way of managing lifetime, which is (as far as I know), similar to a combination of manual "new" and "delete" calls. We cannot use those language features directly, since they also deal with memory.

Removing an entry from its tree requires knowledge of both: the entry and the tree. That is, either you supply both to the destruction function, or you store a tree pointer in each entry. Another way to look at it is: If you already need a `TreeImpl*` in `EntryImpl`, you'll get this for free. On the other hand, the library user might already have the `Tree*` of each entry.

```
class Tree
{
    // [implementation]
public:
    non_owning_pointer<IEntry> AddEntry();
    void RemoveEntry(non_owning_pointer<IEntry>);

    void DoSomething();
};
```

<sub>(After writing this, this reminds me of iterators; though they also allow getting to the *next* entry.)</sub>

With this interface, you can easily write a `unique_ptr<IEntry, ..>` and a `shared_ptr<IEntry>`. For example:

```
namespace detail
{
    class UnqiueEntryPtr_deleter {
        non_owning_pointer<Tree> owner;
    public:
        UnqiueEntryPtr_deleter(Tree* t) : owner{t} ()
        void operator()(IEntry* p) { owner->RemoveEntry(p); }
    };
}

using unique_entry_ptr = std::unique_ptr<IEntry, UniqueEntryPtr_deleter>;

auto AddEntry(Tree& t) // convenience function
{ return unique_entry_ptr{ t.AddEntry(), &t }; }
```

Similarly, you can create an object that holds a `unique_ptr` to an entry and a `shared_ptr` to its `Tree` owner. This prevents lifetime issues of `Entry*` that refer to dead trees.

---

### Lifting the abstraction in PIMPL approaches

Of course, using polymorphism easily allows getting from an `IEntry*` to an `EntryImpl*` inside the library. Can we solve the issue also for the PIMPL approach? Yes, either via friendship (as in the OP), or via a function that extracts (a copy of) the PIMPL:

```
class EntryImpl;
class Entry
{
    EntryImpl* pimpl;
public:
    EntryImpl const* get_pimpl() const;
    EntryImpl* get_pimpl();
};
```

This does not look very nice, but it is necessary for the parts of the library that are compiled by the user to extract that pointer (for example, the user's compiler could select a different memory layout for `Entry` objects). As long as `EntryImpl` is an opaque pointer, one could argue that `Entry`'s encapsulation is not violated. In fact, `EntryImpl` could be well-encapsulated.

Comment: The underlying problem that requires lifting the abstraction from `Entry` seems to be that both `Tree` and `Entry` have them. In a member function of either, you can (without friendship) only access your own pimpl. I have no good solution for that problem.

Comment: Questions regarding software design are generally soft questions, I don't know if the code review site would really be appropriate as well, since I'm not posting actual code, rather a simplified example of the situation. --- Either way, thanks for the response. A few things I omitted in the sample, but are checked for in code. 1. The constructor throws an exception when passed a nullptr. 2. The assignment and copy constructor are actually deleted. --- The `Entry` class and `EntryImpl` indeed have a 1 on 1 relationship. `Entry` exposes some of the functionality of `EntryImpl` to the client.

Comment: But `EntryImpl` contains more information. The relationship between `Tree` and `Entry` is indeed one of ownership. The tree instantiates, owns and destroys an `Entry` when requested by the user. This takes care of several other systems (events, caching, spatial indexing, etc.) which are handled 'under the hood'. The client should never have to worry about how the library does it, and the library should be able to freely change how it does it (better algorithms or other optimizations) without impacting the client's code. The `EntryImpl* const m_Impl;` pointer is an opaque pointer.

Comment: The example using polymorphism is indeed the classic solution, by returning an interface. The upside of this approach is a downside for my scenario. With an interface anybody can implement the interface, and the client may be under the impression that his class that is conforming to the interface is actually a valid parameter. I do not see the advantage of using `non_owning_pointer<T>` since that's exactly what I'm using `T&` for. Being a reference it both indicates that the value cannot be `nullptr` and that it doesn't own memory, it just references it.

Comment: However, the way you use it is exactly the idea I have. I have a `CreateEntry` and `DestroyEntry` method. Though the destruction is deferred/queued to allow other `Entry`'s that also reference this `Entry` to properly clean up before the memory is released. Several events are also fired on the `Entry` itself during this cleanup. That's why I omitted it from my example code, since it'd complicate the example. --- The `unique_entry_ptr` is a nice concept, though I don't know if I can use it. The deleter would require access to the `EntryImpl` which does contain a back-pointer to the `Tree`...

Comment: ...or more precisely, it contains a back-pointer to the object owning `Tree`, which can be different types (either another `Entry` or the 'root'). Point remains, an `Entry` knows how to remove itself. However, I don't think I can implement it without violating the first 'rule' of the project. I don't know if I can use an unimplemented functor as template argument for a unique_ptr. But that's definitely worth a try. I'll hopefully get around to testing that tomorrow. --- Thanks a lot for the effort put into answering my question, I'm going to test all approaches you've shown me!